# laravel mailables -> replace tokens after view rendered

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

following thing:

I read posts from a wordpress database. The idea is that the posts act as master.

E.g. we have a wordpress post with post content:

```
Hi XX_USERNAME_XX,

nice to meet you.

XX_LARAVEL_CONTENT_XX

thanks for your donation of XX_DONATION_AMOUNT_XX

bye
```

I now want to send a normal laravel mailable that when sending out, does the replacements. Now the thing is the views in laravel typically act as master.

in this case though, I want the wordpress post content to be the master, and insert the laravel view into the wordpress content (XX_LARAVEL_CONTENT_XX). And while doing that, replace additional tokens (XX_DONATION_AMOUNT_XX).

How can I do stuff, just before the laravel mailable is rendered? e.g. before the output of the mailable is passed to the mail service, i want to hook in my own filter, take the output from the mailable and put that output into the wordpress post. Is there something supporting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not quite clear to me why you choose to compose your views this way, but in order to achieve this your way, you could use the `callbacks` variable in the Mailable class. They will be [called upon the message](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L219) right after it has been composed from your view

```php
Class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $master;
    publiс $placeholder = 'XX_LARAVEL_CONTENT_XX';

    public function __construct($master)
    {
        $this->master = $master; // 'BEFORE + XX_LARAVEL_CONTENT_XX + AFTER';
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $this->callbacks[] = function ($message) {
            $oldBody = $message->getBody();
            $newBody = str_replace($this->placeholder, $oldBody, $this->master);
            $message->setBody($newBody);
        };

        return $this->view('my-laravel-mail-view') // your normal message setup
            ->to('test@example.com')
            ->subject('Hello');
    }
}
```

And if you want to replace multiple variables, remember that [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) supports arrays as search and replacement:

```
str_replace(['aa', 'bb'], ['AA', 'BB'], $subject);
```

Comment: the reason I chose to do it like this is to allow the client to create all email content in wordpress, with all the tools that come with the wordpress editor and built in functionality, with him being able to do changes himself later on. If you have a better idea, feel free to share